# Presentation API Casting?

Tags: android, dialog, chromecast, google-cast

My app currently uses the Presentation API that was introduced in API 17 to create a "secondary display".  Google just announced that ChromeCast will be able to do screen mirroring this summer.

Does this mean that the Presentation API will detect it as a second screen?

Comment: Possibly, but that's not assured. Creating wireless display protocols is hard, and I will be suitably impressed if Google creates a `LIVE_VIDEO` route that can push across to a Chromecast without doing this at a lower level than usually can be achieved via ordinary SDK apps. What might be happening is that Chromecast OS might be augmented to allow it to act as a Miracast dongle, in which case screen mirroring would "just work".

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you will be able to use Presentation APIs to cast to your second "display".